# What is this socket's name

Tags: usb, socket

I need the socket that looks in the picture. It is like female USB but not with metal case, only inside of female USB. I am looking for black part I will print with 3d printer white part. And is there a 5 pin version?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The photo is too small, there is nothing to show scale and you have not told us where  it is used. Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: I think its name is Hans, but from that angle its hard to tell if I am correct...

Comment: I dont have big picture ı took a screenshot from a video

Comment: Video: https://youtu.be/BK9uWJhJzzI?t=104

Comment: There will be two panel I will use this to connect these panels to eachother there will be 3 data pin , vdd and vss

Comment: Are you trying to build something similar to what is in the pictures, or do you have a damaged panel and you need the exact same part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't deliver a 100% match, but it might be some sort of pcb connector like this

https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-2199170-1.html

But I guess you need the correct dimensions and search the big connector manufacturers yourself. At worst it is a customized part not public available...